# Can you pull out the sign-function out of the integral?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, absolute-value

While playing aroud with integrals I stumbled across following identity:

$\newcommand{\sgn}{\text{sgn}}$
$\sgn(g(x))f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\int\sgn(g(x))f(x)dx\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sgn(g(x))\int f(x)dx\right)$

Which can be easily verified using the chainrule.
The way I interpret this is that when trying to find an antiderivative of a function multiplied by the sign of another function, one can pull the sign-function out of the integral to get a different yet still valid antiderivative.

Example:

$I(x) = \int\frac{|x^3\sin(x)|}{x^3} dx = \int\sgn(x^3\sin(x))\frac{x^3\sin(x)}{x^3} dx =\int\sgn(x\sin(x))\cdot \sin(x) dx = \sgn(x\sin(x))\int \sin(x) dx = \sgn(x\sin(x))(c-\cos(x))$

The annoying part about this is that the sign-function is also multiplied to the constant, but the derivative still yields the original function.

$I'(x) = 0\cdot (c-\cos(x))+ \sgn(x\sin(x))\sin(x) = \sgn(x^3\sin(x))\frac{x^3\sin(x)}{x^3} = \frac{|x^3\sin(x)|}{x^3}$

Is this legitimate or are there some flaws with this?

Comment: The sign function is not itself differentiable.

Comment: Using FTC Part 1, we know $F'(x) = f(x)$ where $F$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. If you know you won't have any differentiability issues when taking the derivative on both sides (which I don't think you should because indefinite integrals are usually defined on some connected subset of the domain of $f$), then I believe the work is valid. However, I would be a bit more careful when applying the same logic to definite integrals because the sign function isn't always a constant that you can just pull out.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few months and I realized the whole thing is trivial.

$\newcommand{\sgn}{\text{sgn}}$

$\displaystyle \int\sgn(g(x))f(x)dx =
\begin{cases}
    \displaystyle \int f(x)dx,& g(x)>0\\
    \displaystyle \int 0 \, dx=0 = 0\cdot\int f(x) dx, & g(x) = 0\\
    \displaystyle \int -f(x)dx = -\int f(x)dx,              & g(x)<0
\end{cases}
 = \sgn(g(x))\int f(x)dx$